Custom XML Parts in Word Online gets removed
I have a Word document that contains Custom XML Parts, and it works perfectly when opened in the Desktop version of Word. Using Office.js, I can successfully retrieve the XML parts with the following method:
Get CustomXML Parts by Namespace
However, when I open the same document in Word Online, the getByNamespaceAsync function returns an empty result. Worse, it appears that Word Online strips out the custom XML parts entirely when the document is opened.
Does the getByNamespaceAsync function not support Word Online? If that's the case, what alternatives should we use instead?
Thanks!

Since the custom parts are stripped out, it makes sense that you'd get an empty result; so the 2nd problem is really the fundamental problem. Please give the community a few days to answer. If you don't get an answer by the weekend, try creating a bug issue on the office-js repo.

I do not know that it is a bug or simply that the Online program is so much less than the desktop applications.
